# How do I use button to refresh the browser page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been learning JavaScript, and have been working on a customizable random number generator. If you decide you want to do more than one, it has to be refreshed. I have tried looping, but that makes it infinite.
Here is the code:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<body>
  <script>
    //This is a simple thingy, to randomly pick a number under a certain number

    //This is how we get what they want the max to be
    var input = prompt("Pick a number to be the maximum");

    //This is what it will output
    var output = Math.floor(Math.random() * (input + 1));
    //The reason for +1 is that it never reaches the max number without it

    //This is the output
    alert(output);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: you could wrap all your code into a function and call that number onclick of a button or hyperlink

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Reload page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    location.reload();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use a loop you can look at the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z1cv7s93/2/

I use a `confirm` to ask if the user wants to continue. If they do they will pick okay, else they chooses cancel and the loop exits.

Here is the code found in the fiddle:

```
var input; 
var contuine = true;
var output; 

while(contuine) {
    input = prompt("Pick a number to be the maximum");
    output = Math.floor(Math.random() * (input + 1)) 
    alert(output);
    contuine = confirm("Contuine?");
}
```

Comment: **redacted** your update took care of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to rerun the script vs actually reloading the page, you could do:

```
<button onlick="randomizer()">Generate Random</button>
<script>
  function randomizer(){
    var input = prompt("Pick a number to be the maximum");
    var output = Math.floor(Math.random() * (input + 1));
    alert(output);
  }
</script>
```

By using a function, you can call a piece of code multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to refresh the page by setting the `window.location` property.  To refresh, just set it to itself:

```
window.location = window.location;
```

To make it happen when a button is clicked, make a button in HTML:

```
<button id="refresh"></button>
```

Then in JavaScript using JQuery, wait until the page is loaded and then make it functional:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#refresh").click(function(event) {
        window.location = window.location;
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see jQuery anywhere in the tags (or anything that would imply its presence)--so why provide an answer referencing it?

Comment: @BradChristie Did you not see it in the title?

Comment: The question is titled "How do I use javascript/**jquery** button to refresh the browser page?"

Comment: Apparently I missed it--used to looking at tags I guess. (Still feel like for a new user jQuery is a bit overkill over fundamental knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

Some simple refactoring can help, but to answer the original question [`window.location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload) is how your refresh a page.

With that said, you can make this entire block of code a function that can be called multiple times. As iut stands, this is executed once because it's not setup to be reusable. However, wrap it in a function:

```
function randomNumber(){
  */ our code */
}
```

Then call it on page load (can be right after the function declaration):

```
randomNumber()
```

Then (optionally) you can bind it to a button so it can be called again. e.g.

```
<button onclick="randomNumber();">Re-run</button>
```